# Private parameters in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am learning `Angular2` and working with `classes` in `javascript` first time.

What does the `private` parameter and why it couldn't be simply `heroService: HeroService` ?

```
constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }
```

Comment: it is a shorthand for `class { s: S; constructor(s: S) {this.s = s} }`. You can also use `public`, `readonly`, or `protected` (but please don't use `protected`).

Comment: @AluanHaddad Why don't to use protected?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Looks like a [parameter property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties). Basically, adding an access modifier (public/private/protected/readonly) to a constructor parameter will automatically assign that parameter to a field of the same name.

Specifically, from those docs:

> TypeScript offers special syntax for turning a constructor parameter into a class property with the same name and value. These are called parameter properties and are created by prefixing a constructor argument with one of the visibility modifiers public, private, protected, or readonly. The resulting field gets those modifier(s)

So the following are equivalent:

```
class Foo {
    private bar: string;
    constructor(bar: string) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}

class Foo {
    constructor(private bar: string) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

private will scope this variable for this class (function). 
public will allow access from outside, if you have the instance of this class. 
protected is important for properties inside a abstract super class. 
As i started with Typescript, playground on the TypeScript page (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) helped me to understand what really happend. Keep in mind, that TypeScript is sugar for your JavaScript